# I am trying to reproduce the exception caused by metamask

Tags: metamask, ethers.js, dapps, react, wagmi

[image]

The purpose of obtaining this image is to aid in my attempts to reproduce the issue. Additionally, I am curious to know if anyone within the community has encountered a similar situation before.

Comment: That's the first time i see that. Is that a bug you encountered yourself or did you pick up the issue somewhere else? If the former, 1) what were you doing exactly? 2) you might want to raise an issue on the metamask-extension github repository  (https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension)

Comment: @Foxxxey I am trying to solve this issue for our product. A customer told me he is facing this. But I don't have the steps to reproduce this.

Comment: "Your product" is metamask? The error message says to report the issue, so the problem is most likely on their end. Ask the customer for details and raise an issue on the mm repo

Comment: In the meantime, ask your user to clear their browser completely and reinstall the extension, i guess.